# Rapidjson output to string not working

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I am trying to use rapidjson to output itself to a string to save to a database, using the following code :

```
StringBuffer buffer;
Writer<FileStream> writer(buffer);
rest.Accept(writer);
string reststring = buffer.GetString();
```

where rest is a rapidjson::Document.

However I get the following error :

```
no matching function for call to ‘rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::FileStream>::Writer (rapidjson::StringBuffer&)’.
```

which is strange because the author of rapidjson recommended this method in an answer to a previous SO question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must have been tired at 9 last night when I wrote this piece of code.

Changing

```
Writer<FileStream> writer(buffer);
```

to

```
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `rapidjson::StringBuffer` and `rapidjson::Writer` for get string output.

```
rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
rest.Accept(writer);
std::string str = buffer.GetString();
```

Here you can get value in both `string` as well as `std::string`.
Above I used `std::string` for get value.
This works...

Answer (score 0):

As your compiler suggest, you have to modify your code in:

```
 StringBuffer buffer;
 Writer<FileStream> writer(&buffer);
```

Or:

```
 StringBuffer* buffer;
 Writer<FileStream> writer(buffer);
```

Comment: Nope. That doesnt work either. The error command proposes no candidate functions, which means I am not even close.